# Trying to understand existence theorem on Rudin's Principles

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm reading Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. It is said in the book, 1.19 Theorem (pg-8): "there exists an ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ which has the least-upper-bound property. Moreover, $\mathbb{R}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield". 
So $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

But in the proof of the theorem (pg-17), it is said that the members of $\mathbb{R}$ will be certain subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

That is to me a contradiction, I mean, if the members of $\mathbb{R}$ will be certain subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, it can't be that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$. ¿What is the explanation for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Well actually there is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ and using this isomorphism we identity this specific subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a standard practice in mathematics. For example there is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (the set of all rationals with denominator $1$) which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus we can treat $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

On page. 17 it is indeed explained that the members of $\mathbb R$ are subsets of $\mathbb Q$ called *cuts*.

Based on that construction, you *identify* each element of $q \in \mathbb Q$ to a unique cut. Namely for $q \in \mathbb Q$ you take the cut $\bar{q}=\{r \in \mathbb Q \ ; \ r <q\}$. Based on that all elements of $\mathbb R$ are subsets of $\mathbb Q$. For example, the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$ is identified to the cut
$$\sqrt{2}=\{r \in \mathbb Q_+ \ ; \ r^2 < 2\} \cup \mathbb Q_-\cup\{0\}$$ which is a subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: But in that case, -2 is not a member of the cut $\sqrt{2}$, I think. But anyway, ¿if we define the real numbers to be subsets of $\mathbb Q$, how can the set of the rational numbers be a subset of the real numbers. Forgive me if I am misunderstanding something, English isn't my native language.

Comment: I indeed made an error in the definition of the cut for $\sqrt{2}$ that I corrected. Formally, you're right. An element of $\mathbb Q$ can not be a subset of $\mathbb R$. But in the construction of $\mathbb R$, a real is a subset of $\mathbb Q$ and you can create a bijection $\varphi : q \mapsto \bar{q}$ where every $\bar{q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb Q$: the cut that I mention above.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I understand what Rudin is saying, but if I wouldn't know what the real numbers are I couldn't understand what Rudin is saying. I mean if I don't know which are the real numbers how can I understand that we can create a bijetion between the reals numbers and the set of these cuts (that are isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$)?